Getting Error: Cannot find module '\node_modules\@sentry\profiling-node\lib\sentry_cpu_profiler-win32-x64-120.node'
[ERROR] 22:19:26 Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\sentry_cpu_profiler-win32-x64-120.node'
Require stack:

D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\cjs\index.js

D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\src\instrument.ts

D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\src\server.ts
[INFO] 22:19:50 Restarting: D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\src\server.ts has been modified
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\sentry_cpu_profiler-win32-x64-120.node'
Require stack:

D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\cjs\index.js
D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\src\instrument.ts
D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\src\server.ts
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at importCppBindingsModule (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\cjs\index.js:166:10)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\module-alias\index.js:49:29)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at importCppBindingsModule (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\cjs\index.js:166:10)
at Object. (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules@sentry\profiling-node\lib\cjs\index.js:169:36)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
at Module._compile (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (C:\Users\juhis\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-19581906753345146.js:114:20)
at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (D:\Toystack\toystack-core-backend\node_modules\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)



I am trying to use yarn add @sentry/node and @sentry/profiling-node  module but constantly it is throwing this error even after installation. and Also tried using yarn install and yarn cache clean. STill not solving. Can anyone help?

You are using a version of node that is too recent. See this GitHub issue.
I had the same error and it went away by downgrading node v23 to node v22.
